# How do we determine the Cut off Probability percent in logistic Regression to segregate customer into good and bad?

Tags: r, regression, logistic

```
New_cust1 <- cbind(New_cust, Prob=predict(fit2, New_cust, type = "response"))
View(New_cust1)
New_cust1$default <- ifelse(New_cust1$Prob>XXX, 1, 0)
sum(New_cust1$default)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find cutoff probability using ROC curve. It's a graph between true positive and false positive. So the trade off between two will give you a cut off probability where it will minimize the false positives.